# Text trimming in the beginning of the string

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have an application in WPF and I want see in my textboxes only the end of the string.

[image]

XAML:

```
  <Grid Height="109" Width="126">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="166*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="145*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="10000004" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="40" Background="LightBlue"/>
    <TextBlock Text="10000005" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="40" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGreen"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

[As you probably have seen on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimmingproperty.aspx), you will need to create/extend with your own TextTrimmingProperty  dependency property.

[Look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597483.aspx) to extend your TextBlock so that you can create your own TextTrimmingProperty to work differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Len = 4; //put this equcal to how many digits you need from last...
//path is the actual string 
string endText = path.Substring(path.Length - Len, path.Length)
```

Comment: thanks, but the number of digits that missing is dynamic, its depends on the control width

Comment: so is there any condition that would specify that control width will contain this much of charaters